# NetSuite NOT a Sales Team Member Saved Search

Tags: search, netsuite, saved-searches

It's easy to do a saved search for when some person is a member of the sales team - how can I search for customers where a particular person is NOT a member of the sales team?

What I'm trying to do is find all the customers in a certain geographical area which do NOT have a certain person in the sales team. They all should; I know some don't, and I need a list of those ones that don't.

Comment: Do you mean a saved search where the salesrep is blank or where salesrep is "not" a sales rep? Say if the sales rep is bill from operations instead of jim/john/bob in sales?

Comment: Where NO member of the sales team is a particular person. I don't care who's in the sales team (or if the sales team is empty); I just want to see customers where John Smith is NOT in any role on the sales team

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sales team enabled on my NetSuite account, so I can't really write it out for you.  But, essentially, you could just script a customer search, and load the sales team for each customer.  Then loop through the team, checking as you go.  If you find the correct person, move on to the next customer, if not, log that customer to a return variable.  Hope that helps...